# What kind of non linear regression model to use when there is very low correlation between independent and dependent variable

Tags: machine-learning, regression

I have a data set with one independent variable(X) and one dependent variable (Y). Since my dependent variable is continuous that's why I am trying regression modeling. As can be seen in the image there is no clear correlation happening between my indep and dep variable. I have already tried linear and polynomial regression but it is giving very poor results. I am stuck and looking for some expert advice on what to do? which model to try
[image]

Comment: Perhaps there is no correlation between X and Y at all. As my suggestion, try taking more into consideration. For example, is X the only independent variable? If not, make it multivariant.

Comment: unfortunately, X is my only independent variable.